# Delete node from binary tree no parent access

Tags: c++, binary-tree, parent

I am doing a class project where we "delete" a node from a binary tree with no access to the parent or root nodes. The way we are shown to do this is just overwrite the old node with the next node on the tree. The problem I am having is when its the last node in the tree(nothing to the right or left after it) I cant overwrite it with the next one so I delete it which leaves me with an empty pointer. I tried just making the value 0(or null) but it throws an error saying the value cant be null. if you have any idea how this can be done your advice would be much appreciated.

```
template< typename T >
inline void Node< T >::delete_node( Node< T > *&p )
{
    cerr<< "delete node" << endl;
    if(p->left() == 0 && p->right() == 0)
    {
        delete p;
    }
    else if (p->left() == 0)//delete p and make the parent point to the right
    {
        //delete p;
        Node< T > *right = p->right();
        p->value(right->value());
        p->left(right->left());
        p->right(right->right());
    }
    else if (p->right() == 0)//delete p ad make the parent move to the left
    {
        //delete p;
        Node< T > *left = p->left();
        p->value(left->value());
        p->left(left->left());
        p->right(left->right());
    }
    else //delete p and go to the right then all the way to the left and attach the other side there.
    {
        Node< T > *tmp = p->left();
        Node< T > *find = p->right();
        Node< T > *right = p->right();

        while(find->left() != 0)
        {
            find = find->left();
        }
        find->left(tmp);

        p->value(right->value());
        p->right(right->right());
        p->left(right->left());
    }
}
```

Comment: `delete p; p = 0;` looks to be the way to go. When you say 'it throws an error saying the value can't be null.' what exactly do you mean?

Comment: if you set p->vaule(0) or null it comes up with the error invalid null pointer. The problem with delete p; p=0; is there is still a pointer that points to p from the parent I dont have access too. so when i go to print the tree out it throws an error because that pointer goes no where. I need to be able to make p nothing without actually deleting it.

Comment: @user2236793, Your delete function takes a reference to a pointer. So my assumption was that it would be called with a reference to the pointer in the parent. If it doesn't then it should, because that way the parent pointer does get set to NULL. Of course it's also possible that you simply have a bug somewhere else in your code, `delete p; p = 0;` is definitely right.